# Creating an SQL table with loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in SQL and PHP. I wanted to create an SQL table in a database with loop where number of columns are as 'Q'. Please help me in understanding where I am wrong in the below code, because its returning a table with only one column name Q1. Thanks.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);

$i = 1;

while ($i <= $QNos){

  $column = 'Q'.$i;
  $sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answerkey_$Test_ID ($column 
  VARCHAR(5))";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die ("ERROR: in Add columns" . 
  mysqli_error($link));
  $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Execute the loop in your head or on paper and see what happens.

Comment: mysql <> sql server.

Comment: If you are trying to add a variable number of columns in a loop then your database design is wrong. Normalize your database.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

You have a `CREATE TABLE` statement inside the `while` loop.

You have also added an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to it, when that line of code, inside the `while` loop, gets send to the db and runs it will do the following.

- Check if table `answerkey_$Test_ID` exists

  - If it exists:
    It will not run the SQL statement
  - If it does not exists:
    It will create the table with the *one* column that the statement declares.

If you didn't have the `IF NOT EXISTS` it would just create the table, still with only *one* column, the first time the statement was executed, then, every time the code inside the `while` loop run, MySql would throw an error, what PHP does with that error depends on your configuration and how you handle it but, you will still end up with a table with only one column.

#### The solution

Take the `CREATE TABLE` statement outside the `while` loop, you should only add a column inside the loop, something like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);

$sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answerkey_$Test_ID (Q1 VARCHAR(5))";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die ("ERROR: in Add columns" . 
    mysqli_error($link));

// I'm assuming you want to start the columns at 1
$i = 2;

while ($i <= $QNos) {

    $column = 'Q'.$i;
    $sql= "ALTER TABLE answerkey_$Test_ID ADD COLUMN $column VARCHAR(5))";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die ("ERROR: in Add columns" . 
    mysqli_error($link));
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @ShailendraPandey if it worked for you don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I guess this is just an exercise, like @symcbean said on the question's comments there is no reason why you should not know the number of columns of your table when you create it, it looks like you have a `1 -> *` relation that you are not modeling properly.